# Property not found in props of React element `form`

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Hi i'm having problems with Flow and React.

I'm getting these errors and I want to get rid of them. What am I missing I have search everywhere. I understand that the props are missing but I can't seem to find where to define them.

**Flow: property `className`. Property not found in props of React element `form`**

**Flow: property `onSubmit`. Property not found in props of React element `form`**

```
export default class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    _submitForm: Function;

    constructor(props?: {}) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            form: {
                email: '',
                password: '',
            },
            errors: {
                _form: "",
                email: "",
                password: ""
            }
        };

        this._submitForm = this._submitForm.bind(this);
    }

    _handleValues(param: string, value?: string) {
        let obj = this.state;

        obj['form'][param] = value;

        this.setState(obj);
    }

    _submitForm(event: Event) {
        this._clearErrors(event);

        let form = this.state.form;

        AxiosQueue
            .post({
                url: LINK.AUTHENTICATE,
                data: form
            })
            .then(({data}) => {
                if (!data.success) {
                    return;
                }
            })
            .catch((response) => {
                console.error(response);
            });
    }

    render() {
        const {errors, form} = this.state;

        const user = UserStore.getUser();
        const formText = FORM_TEXT[user.language || "en_AU"];

        return (
            <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={this._submitForm}>

                {errors._form}

                <InputEmail id="email" error={errors.email} value={form.email} callback={this._handleValues}/>
                <InputPassword id="password" error={errors.password} value={form.password}
                               callback={this._handleValues}/>


                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">{formText.LOGIN}</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is conflict with your variable name `form` in Syntex `const {errors, form} = this.state;` and `form` component. Solution is to give some other name in `this.state`. Like

```
this.state = {
    formValidation:{
        //Validation properties
    }
}
```

And consume so that will remove conflict

```
const {formValidation} = this.state
```